# On click of Radio button, highlight a <p> tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have two Radio buttons with its own labels and paragraph under it. Here's how it looks:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="less_7" name="duration" />
<label for="less_7" id="label_7">Less 7</label>
<p>Less 7</p>

<input type="radio" id="7_10" name="duration" />
<label for="7_10" id="label_10">7 to 10</label>
<p>7 to 10</p>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').click(function() {
        $('label').removeClass('strong');
        $(this).addClass('strong');
    });
});
```

On click of the Radio button, I would like the Paragraph tag which is closest to it to get highlighted with the class strong. On click of any other radio button, its paragraph should get highlighted and the previous one should lose its class.

Currently, I am able to highlight the respective label. I would like to set the class **strong** to the paragraph under it.

My Working Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/ajitks/x83mpjzw/

If the next class can be used, how do I select `$(this + p)`?

Comment: you can also use `:checked` state of `input` https://jsfiddle.net/x83mpjzw/4/

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes - A very elegant and simple solution. Didn't know you can select an element after the most immediate one in CSS using the `+` selector. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').click(function() {
        $('label').removeClass('strong');
        $('label').next('p').removeClass('strong');
        $(this).next('p').addClass('strong');
        $(this).addClass('strong');
    });
});
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0p8rvzhL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('label').click(function() {
    $('label').nextAll('p').removeClass('strong');
    $(this).next('p').addClass('strong');
});
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wsjkdem/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This one will work regardless of what you click - a label or the radio button itself:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        $("input[type='radio']").next('label').removeClass('strong');
        $("input[type='radio']").next('label').next('p').removeClass('strong');
        $(this).next('label').addClass('strong');
        $(this).next('label').next('p').addClass('strong');
    });
});
```

```css
label {
font-weight: normal;
}

.strong {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="less_7" name="duration" />
<label for="less_7" id="label_7">Less 7</label>
<p>Less 7</p>
<input type="radio" id="7_10" name="duration" />
<label for="7_10" id="label_10">7 to 10</label>
<p>7 to 10</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery's **siblings** method to shorten the code.

```js
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') == true ){
            $(this).next().next('p').addClass('strong').siblings().removeClass('strong');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
label {
font-weight: normal;
}

.strong {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="less_7" name="duration" />
<label for="less_7" id="label_7">Less 7</label>
<p>Less 7</p>
<input type="radio" id="7_10" name="duration" />
<label for="7_10" id="label_10">7 to 10</label>
<p>7 to 10</p>
```